# Size Class not working in Today Extensions

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, today-extension

I'm trying to use Size Class to configure a simple UIView in Interface Builder.

This UIView is displayed by a uiviewcontroller which is the root view controller of my widget (set programaticaly).

Whatever Size Class I customize, it is not used and the Any/Any is always used in iPad/iPhone in portrait and landscape.

Are Size Classes supposed to work in Today Extensions ? If so, anyone managed to use it so far ?

Comment: what you mean by Size Class? Do you wan to handle size of UIView for both iPad & iphone device?

Comment: What is a `Size` class I have never heard of this? Do you mean `CGSize`?

Comment: No I really mean Size Class. This is a new way in iOS 8 to handle many form factor and orientation in the same Storyboard/Xib.

Comment: Having the same issue but for a keyboard extension. Filed a bug report so will let you know if dev relations get back to me on this.

Comment: Having the same issue. if anybody came up with a solution or workaround please share

Answer (score 0):

Size classes on the widget is not the same as in an ordinary app since the width and height are different.

On iPad both in lanscape and in portrait the size class is `regular width, regular height` but in the widget it's actually `compact width, regular height`.

Comment: can you tell where to find reference for that? I'd like to know how the other size classes work on the widget.

Comment: @JobertSá, found it simply by logging values.